# What is the reason for this saying?

Tags: idioms, cultural-phrases

***Fences make good neighbors.***

Being a recent purchaser of a new plot and home, I have heard this phrase more than a few times when I spoke of getting a fence.

To me, there is something antisocial and secretive about putting up a boundary (we still very much wanted to put it up).  It seems, then, there is something about getting a fence that serves the harmony of the neighbor relationship.

What is the meaning of this saying?

Comment: This isn’t about English; the phrase would have the same meaning in any language.

Comment: See my prior comment, but: having clear boundaries where each party can act without infringing on the rights of the other, without overlapping or ambiguous territory which is ripe for dispute, allows for better relations. It forestalls arguments and fights.

Comment: The idiom is *good fences make good neighbors*. It means *good fences make for good neighbors* or *good fences result in good neighbors*. I like your version though; it sounds like you would rather have a fence than a person as a neighbor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from  Robert Frost's poem *Mending Wall*.

It is in fact the claim that "*Good* fences make good neighbors." It has been mistaken as advice since then. The source I am adding makes the point that this was not Frost's intention. All who are familiar with the poem would concur.

From
https://www.answers.com Q/Who_is_the_origin_of_good_fences_make_good_neighbors

"The expression comes from Robert Frost's poem Mending Wall. However, it is not Frost, but rather a neighbor, who spouts this cliche. Frost is rather doubtful that it is true. It all depends on whether one is walling in or walling out, and he concludes that there is something that does not like a wall, i.e., essentially a barrier between people."

Comment: It is known from Frost's poem but I do not believe that Frost invented it. In the poem Frost implies that "Good fences make good neighbours" is an established aphorism that people in the area spout without thinking of the real meaning (which I always took to mean that good, sound fences prevented boundary disputes and arguments over straying livestock and consequent crop damage).

Answer (score 1):

"Good fences make good neighbors" means:

> [In general, when you say this phrase, you mean establishing boundaries
> between you and your neighbor helps you both know how to act and
> respect each other's space and privacy.](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-good-fences-make-good-neighbors-mean-699265)

A much rarer variation is "[high fences make good neighbors](https://www.redbubble.com/i/sticker/High-Fences-Make-For-Good-Neighbors-by-AspireDesign/32174745.EJUG5)" which emphasizes how important privacy and minding your own business is to maintaining good relations with those around you.